# Minecraft doesn't work after updating to Windows 8.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, windows-8.1

*Minecraft* has always worked great on this computer, until I updated it to Windows 8.1. I'm not entirely sure if it's because of Windows 8.1, or Java, or my graphic cards (Which it claims to be, but I've updated all the needed ones), or whatever. All of my other games work great. Anyways, here's the crash report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// This doesn't make any sense!

Time: 10/29/14 9:43 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
at bsu.am(SourceFile:523)
at bsu.aj(SourceFile:352)
at bsu.a(SourceFile:299)
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:120)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
at bsu.am(SourceFile:523)
at bsu.aj(SourceFile:352)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
at bsu.a(SourceFile:299)
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:120)

-- System Details --
Details:
Minecraft Version: 1.8
Operating System: Windows 8.1 (amd64) version 6.3
Java Version: 1.7.0_67, Oracle Corporation
Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
Memory: 76715600 bytes (73 MB) / 160890880 bytes (153 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
Launched Version: 1.8
LWJGL: 2.9.1
OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
GL Caps: 
Using VBOs: No
Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
Type: Client (map_client.txt)
Resource Packs: []
Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
```

I don't know too much about computers, but thanks anyways!

Comment: http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/pixel-format-not-accelerated/

Comment: @Ben The Java version is listed in the crash dump and is Java 7.

Comment: update your graphics drivers

Answer (score 7):

It seems like your video card drivers are outdated.

From your crash report:

```
[...]
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated at
org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method) at
[...]
```

From the [Mojang Crash help website](http://hopper.minecraft.net/help/pixel-format-not-accelerated/):

> **Pixel Format Not Accelerated**
>
> This error message is commonly caused by outdated video card drivers.
>   To fix this, you generally need to update your video card drivers,
>   please follow the directions for your Operating System below. If you
>   are having trouble following the directions below, please see this.

---

To update your drivers, you can go your GPU Manufacturer's website and use their "Auto-Detector" to scan your computer for any out-of-date drivers. If one is found, please install the update.

If The auto-Detector says something like "This is incompatible" or "unable to detect system specs" then try to download the manual driver. The manual driver might not install if it doesn't then open the properties and change compatibility and make it run in Windows 7 compatibility mode that fixed it for me.

- Auto-Detector: [AMD / ATI](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/auto-detect-tool), [NVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Scan.aspx?lang=en-us), [INTEL](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect?iid=dc_iduu)
- Manual Driver Search: [AMD / ATI](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx), [NVIDIA](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx), [INTEL](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx)